# How can I run a ruby class from rake file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I want to run a ruby class from a **sample.rake** file.

Consider **myruby.rb** is a ruby file.

I want to run this from **sample.rake** like `ruby myruby.rb`

Comment: http://ericzouthoughts.wordpress.com/2009/06/20/execute-shell-command-in-ruby-rake-task/

Answer (score 9):

Adding to what @tobias has to say here you go with an example script

sample content of `myruby.rb`

```
puts "hello world"
```

Create file called `Rakefile`

```
task :default => [:test]

task :test do
    ruby "my_file.rb"
end
```

Now if you invoke `rake` it should file up `hello world` text in console.

**Update**

It would make more sense if you wrap your call in a function call as suggested already by @tobias

So your `Rakefile` would become something like

```
require './myruby.rb'
task :default => [:test]

task :test do
  ruby "my_file.rb"
end

task :test2 do
  do_something
end
```

and `myruby.rb`

```
def do_something
  puts "do something"
end
```

Now `rake test2` should spit out `do something`

Answer (score 1):

You could use system calls

e.g. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system

Alternatively assuming your reason for doing it this way is that **myruby.rb** is a plain ruby script that just works on execution:

You could think about enclosing the content of the script into a method, `require 'myruby'` in the rake task and executing said method in the rake task.

Comment: myruby.rb is a ruby class. There is no particular method to run from sample.rake. In myruby.rb I have begin...rescue... block thats it. I need to run like 'ruby myruby.rb'. This will bring me what i want.