# unexpected syntax error (

Tags: ruby, rake

I wrote the following code in a file `1_arithmetic.rb`:

```
def arithmetic1(n)
  (n * 5) - 20
end
```

Using the gem tool `rake`, I typed this into the console:

```
rake 1_arithmetic.rb:arithmetic1(5)
```

Then, I got an error message that reads:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Does anyone know where I might have done wrong? Or is the problem the way I used `rake`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass command line arguments to a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task)

Comment: Why are you using rake at all for this? You don't have a rake task here (AFAICT). Use `irb`, expose the method properly, and take it from there.

Comment: cheers, i read my tutorial wrong and it was already programmed with a rake task i could call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe rake can only be used with a rake task. You could create a rake task that then calls your method.

```
require './1_arithmetic.rb'
task :arithmetic, [:n] => [:environment] do |t, args|
  arithmetic1(args[:n])
end
```

You would then call the task using

```
rake arithmetic[5]
```

reference: [How can I run a ruby class from rake file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209388/how-can-i-run-a-ruby-class-from-rake-file)

reference: [How to pass command line arguments to a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task)

Comment: How does that parse in Ruby? `require` doesn't need an `end` and `[n]` seems to reference an unknown variable `n`. `[` is also a shell character that might be interpreted, so if there's a file called `arithmetic5` in the directory that's the argument passed in.

Comment: @engineersmnky That's what I thought. It's a mystery as to why this was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is to run that method, you don't need `rake` to do so, you can just use the `ruby` command:

```
ruby -r./1_arithmetic.rb -e "puts arithmetic1(10)"
```

the `-r` option tells the `ruby` command to `require` the file and the `-e` option tells `ruby` to run the code passed in as a string.

Note: The command posted is assuming the file `1_arithmetic.rb` is in the directory you're running the command from, you'll need to mess with that file path (`./1_arithmetic.rb`) if it's somewhere else.